# Extending java util classes by the book

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am writing a new set of classes to support 2 Key access to maps. Looking at the java.util sources I see that the files there are with ".class" extension, not ".java" and for some reason Eclipse recognizes other classes used in java.util, without any need to declare them in `import`, whether my own class needs the import otherwise Eclipse marks it as error.

<strike>Is there a "book" for doing these kind of things, or guidelines?</strike>

Do I need to rename my .java to .class?

Is it OK to `import` inside my util classes and interfaces, or is there a flag to signal eclipse that this like java.util classes?

Comment: Read up on compilation.

Comment: define `2 Key access`

Comment: read this: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/  In it you will find the concept of "package".  classes in the same package do not need to be imported.

Comment: @DwB I only found a concept how to deploy JAR packages in the link you posted.

Comment: @njzk2 Map<K1,K2,V> instead of Map<K,V>

Comment: read the rest of the page at the link I posted or try a google search for "java tutorial"

Comment: @njzk2 I read the full page, only one "package" refernce, the JAR deployment

Comment: would that have the same behavior as `Map<Pair<K1, K2>, V>`? (Pair is in android.util)?

Comment: @njzk2 Yes, for get and put operations it would be similar. For other operations it becomes more complicated, see my comment to DwB answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Looking at the java.util sources I see that the files there are with ".class" extension, not ".java"

That just means you're looking at the source file attached to the classes rather than a source file in your project. The source itself is still in `.java` files, embedded within the source attachment zip file.

> and for some reason Eclipse recognizes other classes used in java.util, without any need to declare them in import

When you're writing code for a class declared in package `x.y.z`, that package is implicitly imported. So if you're looking at code for classes in `java.util`, they *don't* need to import other classes within `java.util`. They'd need to import classes in other packages such as `java.io` though.